# Theorem formatting

Tags: formatting, theorems

```
\theoremstyle{remark} \newtheorem{example}{Example}
```

Then:

```
\begin{example}
Some text
\end{example}
```

Output is:

```
Example 1. Some text
```

What is the way to automatically obtain without indent:

```
Example 1.
Some text
```

?

I tried to write:

```
\begin{example}
\\Some text
\end{example}
```

But there are two drawbacks, first it must be done every-time, second drawback is that it doesn't compile and Latex error is:

```
./doc.tex:60:There's no line here to end.\\S
```

Comment: thmtools may help, otherwise switch to the ntheorem pacakge and learn to use it. It also have a `\theoremstyle` concept, but it is not about the fonts (as it is with `amsthm`), `\theoremstyle{break}` will do what you want

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's an example of the required new style definition using `amsthm`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}% name
  {3pt}%Space above
  {3pt}%Space below
  {\normalfont}%Body font
  {0pt}%Indent amount
  {\itshape}% Theorem head font
  {.}%Punctuation after theorem head
  {\newline}%Space after theorem head 2
  {}%Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)

\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{exam}{Example}

\begin{document}

\begin{exam}
Test exam
\end{exam}

\end{document}
```

Here's an example using now the predefined `break` style from the `ntheorem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\itshape}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremseparator{.}
\newtheorem{exam}{Example}

\begin{document}

\begin{exam}
Test exam
\end{exam}

\end{document}
```

Finally, here's an example using `thmtools` and `amsthm` as its backend:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=3pt, spacebelow=3pt,
headfont=\normalfont\itshape,
notefont=\normalfont, notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=\newline,
qed=\qedsymbol
]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{example}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
Test exam
\end{example}

\end{document}
```