# Theorem formatting: strange interaction with itemize

Tags: lists, line-breaking, theorems, amsthm

This question is related to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18698/theorem-formatting).

I want to have theorem headers alone on a line like this:

```
Theorem 1.
some text...
```

In the `amsthm` documentation, they suggest doing this:

```
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}{3pt}{3pt}{}{0pt}{\bfseries}{.}{\newline}{}
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
```

And it works... as long as the text of the theorem doesn't start with an itemize or an enumeration.

How can I make it work with `amsthm` in this case?

And... why does this work this (strange) way?

Here is a minimal example to show the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle} % Name
  {3pt}                   % Space above
  {3pt}                   % Space below
  {}                      % Body font
  {0pt}                   % Indent amount
  {\bfseries}             % Theorem head font
  {.}                     % Punctuation after theorem head
  {\newline}              % Space after theorem head
  {}                      % Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning 'normal')

\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{Example}{Example}


\begin{document}

\begin{Example}
  This is on the next line.
\end{Example}

\begin{Example}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item But this isn't!
    \item \ldots
  \end{itemize}
\end{Example}

\begin{Example}~
  \begin{itemize}
    \item And now, there is too much vertical space above
    \item \ldots
  \end{itemize}
\end{Example}

\end{document}
```

Comment: see the solution given here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46357/how-to-suppress-vertical-space-between-theorem-heads-and-enumitem-environments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theorem assumes you start the body with a sentence, not with a list.  The following workaround is available: you may start a bogus paragraph and then backtrack a line up:

```
\begin{Example}\leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item This works
    \item \ldots
  \end{itemize}
\end{Example}
```

Comment: do you know how to remove the horizontal space inserted before the 1st item in a default theorem environment?

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Boris didn't actually solve my problem, when I had the same. The spacing between the Example X text and the list number wasn't right.

But I realized that I could simply write something like this:

```
\begin{Example} $ $
  \begin{itemize}
    \item This works
    \item \ldots
  \end{itemize}
\end{Example}
```

Remark the empty math environment which forces LaTeX the think that there is a text block right after the Example X text.

I just wanted to share my solution, since I wasn't satisfied with the answer provided - I hope it helps somebody.